repetitive error disappear by repetitive f11
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
public class IteratorEx {
public static void main(String[] args) {
String str = "java make world";
//Stream 
IntStream isr = str.chars();

// System.out.print()
isr.forEach(s->System.out.print((char)s));
 
    
}

}
That is all in this progress. at first error came out!
JRE Oracle Corporation/22 is not supported, advanced source lookup disabled.
Eclipse debugger will use less precise source lookup implementation for this debug session, but everything else will continue to work otherwise.
Upgrading Eclipse to the latest version will likely make this warning go away.javamke sesang
without any correction, by repetitive F11 , in the console, i see no error.
i just saw "java make world" . Why did this happen?
